# append to url in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to implement a displayPerPage (10, 25, 50, etc.) when displaying a list of results on an index page. However i'm having a hard time how to just append that to the url without replacing the other query strings.

Example:

I have a paginator to switch pages however, if i'm on page 5 for example and select display per page 10 results on my select dropdown, it will load the results but erase the page=5 from the url. How to I just append displayPerPage without erasing where I currently am on the paginator.

Thanks for any help.

I know its possible to do it without creating a custom paginator since I have done it on another project with laravel 4, but that was a while back and I can't seem to figure out how to do it again.

Comment: if you trying to paginate then you can use this $users = DB::table('users')->simplePaginate(15);

Comment: an can pass this to view

Answer (score 0):

Assuming $objects is the list of the item you're paginating, on your view you can add your paginator like that:

```
{{$objects->appends(request()->query())->links()}}
```

and query strings like your requestPerPage will be carried

Comment: the problem is when I send $displayPerPage to the same url, it does not remember the page number that I was on....I wrote a quick custom url parser function in php and solved the issue that way. I will post it below hopefully it will help someone down the road

Answer (score 0):

After battling with this issue, I wrote a url parser helper function in php to to find and replace certain things in url after the ? sign (query part)

```
//for displayPerPage, orderBy and sortBy parse the url and replace with new values

function urlQueryParse($queryToReplace, $newValue){

//    extract query from url
$fullUrl = Request::fullUrl();

if(strpos($fullUrl, '?') !== false){

    //find everything after the ? in url
    $url = substr($fullUrl, strpos($fullUrl, "?") + 1);

//        check url to make sure $queryToReplace exists in the url

if(strpos($url, $queryToReplace) !== false) {

//        look through the remaining url query and replace whats given to the function
        $newUrL = preg_replace('/('. $queryToReplace. '\=)([^&]+)/', $queryToReplace.'='.$newValue, $url);

        return Request::url()."?{$newUrL}";
    }

//        if the ? exists but the queryToReplace is not in the url, then add it to the query string
    return Request::url()."?{$url}&{$queryToReplace}={$newValue}";

}
//if the url doesnt have ? sign then simply insert the new value
return Request::url()."?{$queryToReplace}={$newValue}";


}
```

Hopefully this helps someone. If you have any ides of how to improve it, I'm open to suggestions.

P.S. I'm working on Laravel 5.2